# Return Spring Boot Error Response as JSON List instead of JSON Object

Tags: spring-boot, rest, error-handling

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ValidationExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void constraintViolationException(HttpServletResponse response,ConstraintViolationException e) throws IOException {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
            strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + '\n');
        }
        ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST);
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    public void dateViolationException(HttpServletResponse response, ValidationException e) throws IOException {
       if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Resource Not Found")){
           ResponseEntity.status(NOT_FOUND);
           response.sendError(NOT_FOUND.value(), e.getMessage());
        }
        else{
            ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST);
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I am formating the Error format for Bad request in Spring boot in below format:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-08-13T09:44:29.000+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "User Not Found in the system",
    "path": "/claims/search/"
}
```

But the Source system needs Error format in Array format like below:

```
[
   {
       "timestamp": "2020-08-13T09:44:29.000+0000",
       "status": 400,
       "error": "Bad Request",
       "message": "User Not Found in the system",
       "path": "/claims/search/"
    }
]
```

Can any one suggest how to add Error structure in Array format?

Answer (score 0):

I've got no single line solution for this, but building your own custom responses is definitely a solution.

```
@Value(staticName = "of")
class ErrorResponseDto(
   Integer status;
   String error;
   String message;
   String path;
)
```

Also provides the advantage that you're free what actually needs to be inside the response:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
public ResponseEntity<List<ErrorResponseEntity>> process(ValidationException ex, WebRequest request) {
   return new ResponseEntity<>(Arrays.asList(generateErrorResponse(ex, request)), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
}

private ErrorResponseDto generateErrorResponseDto(ValidationException ex, WebRequest request) {
    ErrorCode errorCode = ex.getErrorCode();
    String message = ex.getMessage();
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(message))
        message = errorCode.name();

    return new ErrorResponseDto(
        ex.getStatus(),
        ex.getErrorCode(),
        message,
        request.getContextPath()
    );
}
```

You can for example extend it with a unique traceId field or further details about the validation error.

In this case I did not append a timestamp, but the final response will be a list of errors as you need it.

Comment: Thank you for immediate response . I have few queries on your code as I have got some errors by implementing in your way .  1) what is   ErrorCode and there is no isBanlk message in StringUtils. I've tried in below way but it is giving errors while returning response  return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

Comment: @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class) public ResponseEntity<List<ErrorResponse>> process(ValidationException ex, WebRequest request) {return new ResponseEntity<>(Arrays.asList(generateErrorResponse(ex, request)), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    private ErrorResponse generateErrorResponse(ValidationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        String message = ex.getMessage();
        error.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        error.setError(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

Comment: The StringUtils is from apache commons and not from Spring, sorry forgot to mention. The built of the error response should just be an example as I didn't know which exception you're actually catching and what it's containing :) you could just leave out the error code and just go for the message, path & status though

Comment: Can you suggest how to fix this issue compilation error  java: cannot infer type arguments for org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<>

Comment: java: cannot infer type arguments for the below statement . Can you please suggest how to fix the compilation error 
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, NOT_FOUND.value());

Comment: Do not use `.value()` on the HttpStatus :-) The signature of the method actually expects `HttpStatus` enum

Comment: Sorry . I 'm using HttpStatus enum .like this  return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);  . It is throwing an compilation above error at return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

Comment: This should be totally find. You can also try `return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(error)`

Comment: I'm able to set the error response but not not able to set the error and httpCodeMessage .Can you help me please .And it is possible to remove headers and without body the response should be format [
    {
        "headers": {},
        "body": {
            "timestamp": "2020-08-14T20:21:56.256+0000",
            "error": null,
            "message": "User Not Found in the system",
            "path": "/claims/search/",
            "httpCodeMessage": null
        },
        "statusCode": "BAD_REQUEST",
        "statusCodeValue": 400
    }
]

Comment: private Object generateErrorResponse(ValidationException ex, HttpServletRequest req) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
          error.setTimestamp(new Date());
          error.setMessage(NOT_FOUND.value(), ex.getMessage());
          error.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
          error.setPath(req.getRequestURI().toString());
          error.setError(ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST));
         return ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST).body(error);
    }

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to get the values for error and httpCodeMessage in the below format [
    {
        "headers": {},
        "body": {
            "timestamp": "2020-08-17T10:22:14.538+0000",
            "error": null,
            "message": "User Not Found in the system",
            "path": "/claims/search/",
            "httpCodeMessage": null
        },
        "statusCode": "BAD_REQUEST",
        "statusCodeValue": 400
    }
]